# Как передать данные из конструктора одного класса в другой и получить указатель на него?

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть 2 класса. Нужно через конструктор класса B получить указатель на объект А. Каждый экземпляр Б должен иметь свой указатель на А. Хотя если можно без указателей, то тоже пойдёт вариант.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int QRT;

    A(int QRT)
    {
      this->QRT = QRT;
    }  
};

class B {
public:
    int QWE;
    A *obj;
    B(int QWE, int QRT)
    {
        this->QWE = QWE;
        cout << obj <<endl;
        obj = new A(QRT);
        cout << obj <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   B ob1(10,15);
   B ob2(20,25);
   cout << ob1.obj->QRT << endl;
   cout << ob2.obj->QRT << endl;

    cout << ob1.obj << endl;
    cout << ob2.obj << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Я боюсь, что в месте где конструктор B есть утечка памяти. Можете подсказать как грамотнее решить пролему?

Comment: И какие ошибки выдаёт компилятор после правки кода? Здесь нет телепатов.

Comment: @klopp обновил вопрос

Comment: "*Мне постоянно компилятор выдаёт ошибки в том месте*" - в каком месте и какие именно?

Comment: @klopp, я просто неправильно присваивал указателю новый объект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибок компилятора не нужно бояться. Их нужно читать и делать выводы, именно для этого они и предназначены. Например, здесь выдаётся (g++, наверняка у вас что-то аналогичное):

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(int)’
    B ob1(10);
            ^
...
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Ну английским же по-белому написано, что компилятор не может найти конструктора `B(int)`. И даже подсказывает, что единственный конструктор вашего класса `B` описан с двумя аргументами, а вы вызываете конструктор с одним аргументом.

Выводы попробуйте сделать самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо, но эту ошибку я быстро исправил. У меня  другая пролема. Посмотрите на код выше (я его обновил). Попробуйте его исполнить. Я вывел адреса указателей. Мне чёто очень кажется что в конструкторе B будет нехилая утечка памяти (интуиция). Так ли это?

Comment: Утечки памяти нужно отлавливать не интуицией, а специальными утилитами, начиная с банального отладчика, и заканчивая этими: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347 А ещё головой :) Навскидку - где удаление созданных объектов в деструкторе `B`? А адреса указателей вам ни о чём не скажут. Тем более что вы выводите мусор (неинициализированные переменные).

Comment: Утечка памяти будет не в конструкторе, а потому что ты не потрудился сделать деструктор, который бы освобождал поле obj. Также не помешает конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания. Это конечно если хочется идти наиболее трудным путем. А по нормальному почему бы не сделать A obj полем класса B? И не страдать фигней с ручным выделением памяти.

Answer (score 0):

предлагаю такой вариант

```
class A {
 int QRT;
public:

 A(int QRT_) : QRT( QRT_ ) {}
};


class B {
    A obj;
    int QWE;
public:
    B(int QWE_, int QRT_) : obj( QRT_ ), QWE( QWE_ ) {}
};
```